# Creating day count using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe,

| ID | d_of_stay |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2021-03-02 |
| 1 | 2021-03-03 |
| 2 | 2021-03-05 |
| 2 | 2021-03-06 |

I have to create a column like below,

| ID | d_of_stay | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | Day 0 |
| 1 | 2021-03-02 | Day 1 |
| 1 | 2021-03-03 | Day 2 |
| 2 | 2021-03-05 | Day 0 |
| 2 | 2021-03-06 | Day 1 |

How to do that using pandas/python?

Comment: Explanation of the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the results you expect IIUC

```
df['day'] = df.groupby('ID')['d_of_stay'].cumcount()
df['day'] = 'Day ' + df['day'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Oh no I misread thought he started at 1 i'll update thank you

Comment: It should be without +1, so it starts from 0